# servlet WebSocket (without annotation)

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, annotations, web.xml

Can anyone gave a method to create websocket on java without annotation (as a servlet) by create servlet class and point to it through web.xml.

Comment: Please read the guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions and edit your question to have more info. Which code do you have already and what are you trying to achieve, what's the app server, ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the below answer as an explanation to create the web.xml file for your websocket example. Though if you post the part where you are stuck, we may be able to help you better.

The web.xml contains `<servlet-mapping>` and `<servlet>` tags.

Nested in the `<servlet-mapping>` is `<url-pattern>` tag within which you specify what you have given in your html action, but it should be preceeded by a '/'.

The `<servlet-name>` inside the `<servlet-mapping>` tag, can contain any name that you provide, say 'servletx'. This name should match with the `<servlet-name>` tag which is nested in the `<servlet>` tag.

The `<servlet>` tag along with containing `<servlet-name>` also contains another tag called `<servlet-class>.`

Within `<servlet-class>` is the actual name of the servlet class (.java) that you have written and want to be called.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <display-name>HelloWorld Application</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>examples.Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: can you put the java class "examples.Hello"